# $Ax \leq 0$ always has solution given randomly drawn $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $A$ is $n \times d$, where each row of the $n$ rows of $A$ is randomly drawn from the uniform distribution over the unit sphere.

I was curious: is it true that, almost surely, $Ax \leq 0$ has a non-zero solution, $x \neq 0$ (even if $n >> d$)?

Comment: yes, think of some special case. Hint: we can pick the same $x$ for all $A$.

Comment: $Ax$ is a vector. What does $Ax<0$ mean?

Comment: Oh $0$ is the $d$-dimensional all zero vector.

Comment: And thanks for the catch, I've modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try $n=3, d=2$.  $(Ax)_i$ is the dot product of $x$ with a randomly chosen unit vector in $\mathbb R^2$, and is negative for $x$ in an open half-plane.  With nonzero probability the intersection of these three half-planes is empty.  In fact, the intersection of the first two half-planes is a sector of opening angle $\theta \le \pi$ and almost surely $< \pi$.  Then if the third row of $A$ is in a sector of opening angle $\pi - \theta$, the corresponding half-plane will be disjoint from the intersection of the first two.